# Highcharts Bubble chart mouseover breaking animation

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Good day, trying to figure out one last piece with a code rewrite that we've been working on. We have a bubble chart that animates, to essentially simulate a motion chart, since most of the motion chart libraries we relied on previously incorporated flash.

It seems like the mouseover space for the original render sticks around during animation, and causes the bubbles to "reset", I've noticed the tooltips also stick to the original location. Any ideas/suggestions?

I've copied up a mostly complete version here (the loading of additional variables isn't implemented):

https://nl.communityaccounts.ca/motionchart/motion_dev.asp

I'm working on a standalone jsfiddle as well, can put a link to that soon.

Comment: I may have just figured it out, it looks as though the tooltips were set to shared and therefore drawing off the original objects, which might have messed up the positioning? Trying to dig into it.

Comment: Hi @jdower27, Could you try to reproduce the problem with minimal configuration in jsfiddle? You can start from: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/

Comment: I'll have a look, starting from there is pretty rough, so I'll see about working backwards, I didn't get the jsfiddle working yesterday.

Comment: Hi again, I went back to a fiddle you actually provided when I was digging through some issues with highcharts 5, and it appears this problem was introduced with Highcharts 6. I'm not sure what's changed there. Of course even 6 is relatively old, so I'm not sure we're going to be able to resolve this. I may end up looking at other libraries in the meantime.

https://jsfiddle.net/ygsuj4rc/1/

Comment: Another fiddle with some more information stripped out, and shows the issue a bit more clearly. If you press play, it's like the original "display" listeners stick around the original location, even if the circles themselves move. I wonder if there's a way to trigger those to refresh? Or remove them? https://jsfiddle.net/wyzvomb4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highcharts uses `plotX` and `plotY` point's properties to position the tooltip in a default way. In your case, only properties: `x`, `y`, `z` and point's graphic are updated. You need to also update `plotX` and `plotY`:

```
dataObject.plotX = data.x + data.z;
dataObject.plotY = data.y + data.z;
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9drynwcz/

Comment: Interesting, another layer. However I've noticed the bubbles still get "stuck' if you mouseover them enough during animation. I'm sure there's a logical reason why, perhaps there is another property that we are not aware of that's been incorporated as of version 6? It doesn't seem like we were trying to do something particularly extreme when we built this, but it sure keeps causing issues! I can record a gif/video if the same doesn't happen with you, but even removing all the mouseover/tooltips the bubbles will "stick" and render in their original location randomly.

Comment: Hi @jdower27, Maybe because states are disabled for a series, not for a marker? Please check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/k8vbqyL4/ and let me know if that helped.

Comment: Unfortunately, no, it still appears to have the same issue. Frustrating, I'll play around with it some more, if you have any additional ideas, it would be greatly appreciated.

I didn't get far with the support option with Highcharts. I know we were extending highcharts a bit, but it seemed to be a good solution vs starting from scratch with another library. It's also not something a lot of people have been trying to do, so I don't know if starting over with version 8 or 9 would get us much further.

Comment: Could you create a gif/video that you mentioned to be at the same point?

Comment: Sure:
[https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ImBE6qrfTqw4vBy_1A5-GQKLJH6uR3Oj/view?usp=sharing]

This is fairly low quality and extreme mouse behaviour, but this is what keeps happening. Has to be something related to "listening" still sticking around I would think? Tough to restart as well, since the rendering of animation updates does seem to have changed a fair bit with 7 onwards.

Comment: Hello @jdower27, I have found the problem. The `complete` function is not fired after mouseover because Highcharts call own animation in `setState` method. As a solution overwrite the method, example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ekbz60ar/

Comment: Wow, I had tried putting logging in virtually everywhere to try and trace where that was failing, but I couldn't have tried there, it didn't even occur to me. Perhaps that's one of those pieces that's changed since we originally designed it? I was once more versed in how the inner workings of highcharts functioned, but as you can tell, have fallen out of practice. Going to have to get more involved obviously. I will continue to test, but it looks like you cracked it.

Comment: I am glad that I could help. Please feel free to ask in case of future problems :)